# How to run/generate xtext artifacts for MyDsl.xtext in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, dsl, xtext

I get a running workflow problem when trying to generate xtext artifacts for MyDsl.xtext in my dsl editor(eclipse). It says "Problem runnig workflow : Please put bundle org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch on your project classpath". I tried some solutions on the internet, but I still get the problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whWO8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7PZm.png)

Comment: is this an eclipse project or a gradle project or a prue maven project?

Comment: eclipse project

Answer (score 0):

you can add it to the manifest in either Required Plug-ins or Automated Management of Dependencies sections. If you create the project with the Wizard this should happen automatically.

[image]

Comment: I created the project using the Wizard.

Comment: does the project show any errors or warnings? is the mwe.launch in the list as above?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the package explorer of the mydsl project with "Plugin-dependencies" node expanded

Comment: open the manifest.mf file and go to dependencies tab

Comment: I have added a screen

Comment: it looks like you have a problem with your target platform or dont have plugin develop environment installed. easiert is to pick this distro https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-12/r/eclipse-ide-java-and-dsl-developers or you install it via the Help Dialog